# Asynchronous publish and subscribe messages is not working in pubnub

Tags: javascript, node.js, pubnub

I am using the following code for `pubnub` connection.

```
pubnub = new PubNub({
    subscribeKey: "demo",
    publishKey: "demo",
        keepAlive: true,
})
pubnub.addListener({
    message: function(message){
        console.log(message.channel+' '+message.publisher+' '+message.message.name+' '+time)
},
    status: function(s) {
        console.log(s.category+" "+s.operation+" "+s.affectedChannels +" "+s.subscribedChannels +" "+s.affectedChannelGroups+" "+time+" "+s.message)
    }
 });
 pubnub.history(
 {
    //child0, new
    channel: 'child3',
    reverse: true,
    count: 10
 },
 function (status, response) {
    // console.log(response);
    console.log(response.messages);
 }
 );
 pubnub.subscribe({
     channels: ['child3'],
     // resubscribe and reconnect
     restore : true, 
     //callback: function(m){console.log(m)} ,
 });
```

I had two nodejs scripts, one for publish and another for subscribe a message in `pubnub`.

When the Subscriber is online, it is able to receive messages from the Publisher but when the Subscriber goes offline, it is unable to receive the appropriate message from the Publisher due to a faulty network connection, occurring due to an erroneous Subscribe Script.

Please resolve this issue.

Comment: Where is your publish and subscribe code? By the way, your `heartbeatInterval` value is way too low. Just remove that line and the `presenceTimeout` setting will auto config the `heartbeatInterval` to the best value.

Comment: And did that fix your issue with pub/sub not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PubNub Subscribe Online vs Offline

> When the Subscriber is online, it is able to receive messages from the Publisher but when the Subscriber goes offline, it is unable to receive the appropriate message from the Publisher due to a faulty network connection, occurring due to an erroneous Subscribe Script.

This is completely expected. You say *erroneous subscribe script* but there is nothing erroneous about it. Nothing is going to work unless you are **connected**. Once your app is *offline*, how would you expect the app to receive any messages? So there is no error here with PubNub. It working as it should.

Get connected and you will get messages.